# Launch Screen Localized Image not rendering

Tags: swift, xcode7.3

Problem: The Launch Screen Image is either not rendering (white space where UIImage should be), or not being localized.

My project is set up to load the LaunchScreen from Launch.storyboard via the target's General configuration.

Some facts:

1. XCode 7.3
2. Multiple Targets with unique Launch.storyboards.
3. Tried with two images one was a localized Image.png file (in resources, not in .xcassets), the other was 2 unique image sets in
   .xcassets one named "image_en" the other "image_fr".

Some things I tried:

1. Cleaning the project, resetting the simulator, restarting xcode,
   deleting the app's DerivedData.
2. Created a new Master-Detail project and localized the LaunchScreen.storyboard file. Then added
   image_en in en.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard and replaced the image
   in the fr.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard with image_fr .xcassets files
   this solved the image not loading problem, but the image was still
   not localized.
3. Created a new Master-Detail project and localized the LaunchScreen.storyboard file. Then I localized the Image.png and added it to the LaunchScreen. This image appeared, but wasn't localized.

Question: Why is a black void appearing in the Launch Screen localized Image.png in my original project? && is this an xcode bug or am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: Could you send me a screenshot of all your files including the launch screen file?

Comment: Just update your answer with the pic

Comment: The black-void image issue seemed to have fixed itself, so it might have been a device issue. The only one remaining now is that the Launch Screen Image is not localized.